# How to stop images movement after border hover?

Tags: html, image, css

I have 3 images that i coded via css to have border hover. 
It is simple and nice but the images keep moving when hover.

http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/cam.jpg  
  http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/car.jpg  
  http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/phone.jpg

Here is live: **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/8Ly9jyrh/)**

Here is the code:

```
<center>
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars"><img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/cam.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars"><img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/car.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/tickets"><img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/phone.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>
</center>
```

and here is the css:

```
a.round:hover {border: 5px solid #005FD0; display: inline-block; position: static;
    cursor: pointer;  }
```

What is the correct css method i need to use to keep them in place when hovring?

Comment: Also worth noting you're trying to change the display property of the element upon hover - it's best to set this on the element itself to avoid sudden changes to movement as your display type is irrelevant with regards to your hover effect.

Comment: @Doidgey Same. Actually, I'd say the only thing you want to change on hover is `border-color`. You don't want to change `border-width`, `border-style`, `display`, `position`, or `cursor` (Cursor already represents something that will only take effect when your mouse is hovering on it, so putting it inside a hover rule is just redundant)

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @Katana314 OK. so what do you suggest? put the style on the a or img tag?

Comment: @StackBuck `a` tag. All those properties I just mentioned in my second sentence, I'd recommend go under a separate rule that's the same as the first, but without `:hover`. (In fact I have a feeling some are already in such a rule, which causes it to look as it does now)

Comment: @Katana Anything wrong with what sebastianbrosch wrote. Becouse for my opinion it is the best shut. Do you agree?

Comment: @StackBuck I agree, box shadow seems like a very good approach because it won't affect the item's layout at all. No issues from what I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `box-shadow`:

```css
img:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #005FD0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #005FD0;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px #005FD0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars">
    <img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/cam.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars">
    <img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/car.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/tickets">
    <img src="http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/phone.jpg" width="200" height="200">
  </a>
</center>
```

Comment: Yep. your solution did it slightly! https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/9bgvuq19/

Answer (score 3):

Give the non-hovered state a transparent border:

```
a.round {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    position: static;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8Ly9jyrh/7/)**

Note also that you may want to give the images a `vertical-align:top;` rule to remove the gap below them. And please don't use the `<center>` element.

Comment: You got me before i was finish answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to give the original a transparent border:

```
border: 5px solid transparent;
```

Edit: Someone was before me. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

It took me some time but here it is:

Live here: **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/8Ly9jyrh/3/)**

```
<center>
<a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars">
<div class="banner">
</div>
</a>
<a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars">
<div class="banner1">
</div></a>
<a class="round" href="http://coreneto.com/rental/cars">
<div class="banner2">
</div>
</a>
</center>
```

and

```
a {decoration:none}

 div:hover{border: 5px solid #005FD0;}

 .banner , .banner1, .banner2 {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 200px; 
  height: 200px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
  } 

.banner {background: url(http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/cam.jpg) no-repeat center center;}

.banner1 {background: url(http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/car.jpg) no-repeat center center;}

.banner2 {background: url(http://coreneto.com/rental/static/dist/img/phone.jpg) no-repeat center center;}
```